# What is the best way to interface with a a program that uses filenames on the command line for input and output?

Tags: c, process, pipe, temporary-files

I need to interface with some executables that expect to be passed filenames for input or output:

```
./helper in.txt out.txt
```

What is the standard (and preferably cross-platform) way of doing this?

I could create lots of temporary files int the `/tmp` directory, but I am concerned that creating tons of files might cause some issues. Also, I want to be able to install my program and not have to worry about permissions later.

I could also just be Unix specific and try to go for a solution using pipes, etc. But then, I don't think I would be able to find a solution with nice, unnamed pipes.

---

My alternative to this would be piping input to stdin (all the executables I need also accept it this way) and get the results from stdout. However, the outputs they give to stdout are all different and I would need to write lots of adapters by hand to make this uniform (the outputs through files obey a same standard). I don't like how this would lock in my program to a couple of formats though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a right or wrong answer necessarily.  Reading/writing to stdin/out is probably cleaner and doesn't use disk space.  However, using temporary files is just fine too **as long as you do it safely**.  Specifically, see the `mktemp` and `mkstemp` manual page for functions that let you create temporary files for short-term usage.  Just clean them up afterward (`unlink`) and it's just fine to use and manipulate temp files.

Comment: Is there any rule of thumb / best practice about how should I choose the `mkstemp` templates or do I just use the first thing that comes to my head?

Comment: The nice think about mkstemp is that even if you pick a template that is in use by another program, you're *still* going to get a unique file.  So no, pick what you want for yourself.  You might want a reasonable extension just because it's helpful to the world.  EG, ".txt" for text files.